# Swiper slider empty spaces

Tags: slider, swiper.js

I have some problem with Swiper slider. When i scroll to the end of slider, some empty spaces is visible.

http://take.ms/siqXj

```
swiper = new Swiper(profile_images, {
    slidesPerView: 4,
    nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
    observer: true
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/x2zu5ett/1/

> UPDATE
>   Solution: set 'slidesPerView' attribute to 'auto'

Comment: Please post source code or create a working example at jsfiddle

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/x2zu5ett/1/

Answer (score 0):

Do you still need help?
Try to add this: `loopFillGroupWithBlank: false,`

Check mine:

```
var swiper2 = new Swiper('.swiper-container2', {
    slidesPerView: 'auto',
    centeredSlides: true,
    spaceBetween: 150,
    speed: 1500,
    loop: true,
    simulateTouch : true,
    loopFillGroupWithBlank: false,
    grabCursor: true,
    //touchStartPreventDefault: false,
});
```

Comment: `loopFillGroupWithBlank: false` - default option

Answer (score 0):

https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#param-centeredSlidesBounds

check `centeredSlidesBounds` param. It will remove black spaces in begging and ending of slides-wrapper.

Answer (score -1):

Still having such issues ?
try setting

> width: auto;

on swiper

Comment: It doesn't work for me