# Swiper Slider is creating blank spaces after last slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, phonegap, html-framework-7, swiper.js

I'm using Swiper Slider for a hybrid app i'm creating using Phonegap with Framework 7.

Each slide is made with dynamic content that is being brought through an Ajax call.

The problem is that i have two Sliders in the same page, and when i reach the last slide on both of them, a huge blank space starts appearing and the more we slide with our finger, the more blank space it will create.

I will leave here some prints and the relevant bits of code.

My HTML File:

```
    <div class="ementa-sobre pl30 mt60">

         <h3 class="titulo-v1">Ementa <div class="circulo-pequeno"></div> <span class="info-complementar-titulo" id="numero-pratos"></span></h3>

        <div class='swiper-container swiper-ementa-home'>
              <div class='swiper-wrapper' id="slider-ementa-home">
              </div>
        </div>


    </div>



 <div class="eventos-sobre pl30 mt60">

          <h3 class="titulo-v1">Eventos <div class="circulo-pequeno"></div> <span class="info-complementar-titulo" id="numero-eventos"></span></h3>

          <div class='swiper-container swiper-eventos-home'>
              <div class='swiper-wrapper' id="slider-eventos-home">
              </div>
          </div>


</div>
```

My JS File:

```
myApp.onPageInit('home', function (page) {


    $(document).ready(function()
    {

var ajaxurl3="myurl.php";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: ajaxurl3,
            success: function(data) {
                $.each(data, function(i, field){
                    var id=field.id_categoria;
                    var nomeCategoria=field.nome_categoria;
                    var imgCategoria=field.img_categoria;
                    var string = "<div class='swiper-slide' style='background-image:url(https://pizzarte.com/app/img/ementa/"+imgCategoria+")'><a href='pratos.html?idcat="+id+"&cat="+nomeCategoria+"'><p>"+nomeCategoria+"</p></a></div>";
                    $("#slider-ementa-home").append(string);

                })
            },
            complete: function (data) {
                var mySwiper2 = myApp.swiper('.swiper-ementa-home', {
                    spaceBetween: 15
                  });
               }
        });



        var ajaxurl4="myurl2.php";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: ajaxurl4,
            success: function(data) {
                $.each(data, function(i, field){
                    var id=field.id_evento;
                    var nomeEvento=field.nome_evento;
                    var imgEvento=field.img_evento;
                    var string = "<div class='swiper-slide' style='background-image:url(https://pizzarte.com/app/img/eventos/"+imgEvento+")'><a href='eventos.html?idcat="+id+"&cat="+nomeEvento+"'><p>"+nomeEvento+"</p></a></div>";
                    $("#slider-eventos-home").append(string);

                })
            },
            complete: function (data) {
                var mySwiper3 = myApp.swiper('.swiper-eventos-home', {
                    spaceBetween: 15
                  });
               }
        });


 });
})
```

Prints:

- When page loads (everything is fine): https://gyazo.com/42094ad145607579572eb550a2d22d28
- Scrolling to the last slide (lots of blank space): https://gyazo.com/64f5ec3b4d9c2e1f77357d2a040ea153
- If we continue to scroll (if we keep scrolling, it will keep adding blank space): https://gyazo.com/f9e1be36eabbcafdd8767b05a29d2259

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Maybe your `spaceBetween: 15` is the problem?

Comment: even if your ajax return empty data it keeps on appending those. that what giving you empty space. validate that if ajax return is empty dont append data to swiper.

Comment: @prasannaputtaswamy following your advice i tried using this, but it didn't work. Could you advise me on how to do it?
https://gyazo.com/bae24cabc08eca5e9e566268c86ec6c1

Comment: @EduardoJoão Did you tried to remove spaceBetween?

Comment: have you checked/validated for empty/blank for two function.

Answer (score 3):

As [demkovych](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3153799/demkovych) said ([here, dublicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32650297)), add:

```
slidesPerView: 'auto'
```

Comment: It does n't work for me

Answer (score 2):

In your Swiper Initialization portion, use **slidesOffsetAfter: 0**, See bellow example for more details:

```
<script>
    var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
      slidesPerView: 3,
      spaceBetween: 30,
      slidesOffsetAfter:0,
      freeMode: true,
      pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
        clickable: true,
      },
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: It does n't work for me

Comment: Please check it with multiple version of Swiper Js and double check your CSS files maybe it effects from other source, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to add `loopFillGroupBlank: false,` like this:

```
complete: function (data) {
    var mySwiper3 = myApp.swiper('.swiper-eventos-home', {
        spaceBetween: 15,
        loopFillGroupBlank: false,
    });
}
```

Comment: `loopFillGroupBlank` is `false` by default.

Answer (score 0):

In Vue.js (and likely in other frameworks as well), creating a loop directly from a source array and modifying that array on the fly can lead to repeated blank elements. As a solution, I am calling following function after every modification.

```
function clearEmptyElements() {
  const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.swiper-slide-blank');
  elements.forEach(el => el.remove());
  swiperInstance.update();
}
```